# Is there a way to use "for loop" in creating a matrix

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

I'm a total beginner when it comes to MATLAB, so I have a question for this. How am I supposed to write this code out and if by any chance, can someone be kind enough to write out the code because I've been struggling with this. Use loops to create 3 x 5 matrix in which the value of each element is half of its row number plus three times its column number. for instance, the value of element (2,5) is: 1/2*2+3*5

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! I'd advise for next time to try to post a code attempt. The community is a lot more helpful when that happens. Some other things that might be helpful are diagrams if no code attempt can be provided.

Answer (score 0):

The nested loops control the indexing of the matrix. The outer for-loop traverses through the rows of the matrix and the inner for-loop traverses through the columns of the matrix.

The second part of this question requires using a combination of the looping/scanning variables `Row` and `Column` to set the value of the matrix:

**Matrix Value = (Row ÷ 2) + (3 × Column)**

```
Number_Of_Rows = 3;
Number_Of_Columns = 5;

Matrix = zeros(Number_Of_Rows,Number_Of_Columns);
    
%Running through the array indices using two loops%
for Row = 1: Number_Of_Rows
   for Column = 1: Number_Of_Columns 
    
%Evaluating the value based on the current row and column index%
Matrix(Row,Column) = (Row/2) + (3*Column);
       
   end
end

Matrix
```

### Result:

[image: Matrix Values]

### Looping Methodology:

[image: Looping Methodology]

### Variable Matrix Opened In Workspace:

[image: Matrix Array]

Answer (score 0):

Here's an intuitive way to do this:

```
% Initialize row num and column num
row = 3;
column = 5;
% H is the matrix of desire
% Initialize it as a 3*5 zero matrix  
H = zeros(3,5);

% Outer loop, over column index
% Remember Matlab's index start with 1 not 0
for c = 1:column
    % Inner Loop, over row index
    for r = 1:row
        % The algorithm of each element in the matrix
        H(r,c) = 0.5*r+3*c;
    end
end
```

Comment: please add explaiantion of what u did